# Conditional removal of decimals on formatted money values using Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to remove the decimals on my formatted numbers but only if certain conditions are met.

conditions:

if num < 100 - keep the decimal value

if num > 99.9 && the decimal value == .00 - remove the decimal value

else if num > 99.9 && has decimal value - keep the decimal value

Heres the function I use to format my number:

```
formatMoneyValue(value) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' }).format(value);
}
```

Comment: and... what have you tried so far? are you looking for someone to just solve this for you? you are not new to StackOverflow, you know this is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Dekel I'm more than willing to do this myself if someone points me in the correct direction. I just have no idea how to even start

Comment: Well, you have two choices; check the `value`, pass in the appropriate `options` (including `maximumFractionDigits`) according to the rules laid out above, or take the string produced by `format` and truncate as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `minimumFractionDigits` option for this like:

```js
function formatMoneyValue(value) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'GBP',
    minimumFractionDigits: (value > 99.9 && value%1===0) ? 0 : 2,
  }).format(value);
}

console.log(formatMoneyValue(80.00))
console.log(formatMoneyValue(90.88))
console.log(formatMoneyValue(150.00))
console.log(formatMoneyValue(160.55))
```

Comment: Does "value%1===0" reference the decimal value?

Comment: Yes, a simple example would be `5.01 % 1 === 0` is false and `5.00 % 1 === 0` & `5 % 1 === 0` both are true.